# Can standard Apache ActiveMQ run on Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL)?

Tags: activemq-classic, rhel

Does RHEL require the use of [RedHat JBoss A-MQ](http://www.jboss.org/products/amq) or can standard AMQ run on RHEL?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in the RHEL license that requires you to use their solutions.  We use ActiveMQ on RHEL in production all of the time.